# rewrite rules to redirect `name` and `name/` to `name.php`

Tags: .htaccess, routes

I'm trying to drop the file extension and create a mini router that redirects several pages based on their name, where `name` and `name/` are redirected to `name.php` in htaccess

this is what I have now (including removal of www)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd rule will not work since `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` will not have `.php` in it when you enter `/name/` in the browser.

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be doing anything

Comment: What URL did you use to test? Where is this .htaccess located and what error did you get? Provide as much information as you can.

Comment: Also tell me if `/name/` is a real directory?

Comment: That was my 2nd comment. I asked few questions in my first comment also.

Comment: oops, missed that, I'm testing on a local XAMPP, I have no folders, just a php file and an .htaccess file

Comment: But then how are you using `www` removal rule in local XAMPP?

Comment: right, in production I'm using it, but testing it locally has no effect.

Comment: Yes but please help me understand how are you testing `www` removal code on localhost. In any case both rules are well tested and working on my Apache web server (I created a host entry with `www.localhost` also).